# How to display headlines in marquee in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in `codeigniter` framework of PHP. I want display the news headlines in scrolling `marquee` I tried this

**view page**

```
<marquee bgcolor="black"><font color="white">
<?php 
            foreach($news as $row)
{
$heading=$row->st_head;
 echo $heading;

}
?>
</font ></marquee>
```

**controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Headlines extends CI_Controller {



    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Headlines_model');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $where_cond = "flg_is_active = 1";
            $select_cond = "st_head,in_news_id";
            $data['news'] = $this->Headlines_model->select_records($where_cond,$select_cond );

            $this->load->view('Headlines',$data);
        }
    }
```

*****Model **************

```
 <?php
    class Headlines_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->table_name = 'tbl_news';
        }

        public function select_records($where=NULL,$select=NULL,$jointable=NULL,$joinkey=NULL,$per_page=NULL,$limit=NULL,$order_by=NULL, $count = false)
        {

            if($where!=NULL)
                $this->db->where($where);

            if($select!=NULL)
                $this->db->select($select);

            if($jointable!=NULL && $joinkey!=NULL)
                $this->db->join($jointable, $joinkey);

            if($limit!=NULL || $per_page!=NULL)
                $this->db->limit($limit, $per_page);

            if($order_by!=NULL)
                $this->db->order_by($order_by);

            $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);

            if($count==true)
            {   
                return $query->num_rows();
            }
            else
            {
                return $query->result();
            }
        }

        }

    ?>
```

if I display without `marquee` the show the data properly. But when I use marquee then it gives following error

> PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: news
>
> Filename: views/Headlines.php
>
> Line Number: 2

Comment: Post code of model file too

Comment: What you get if you print_r($data['news']); ?

Comment: What is the exact code you are using? The html has no effect on the php and the `foreach` is on line 3 and not line 2 in your example.

Comment: It give an error to foreach. If I remove foreach then it give error to echo.